# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ belong to a commutative ring $R$. If $a$ is a unit of $R$ and $b^{2}=0$ . Show that $a+b$ is a unit of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ belong to a commutative ring $R$. If $a$ is a unit of $R$  and $b^{2}=0$ . Show that $a+b$ is a unit of $R$

I try it..

consider $(a+b)(b)=ab+b^{2}=ab=1$ Since a is unit

Comment: Consider $(a+b)(a-b)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the product of two units is not $1$, but you are on the right track.

In fact, a more general statement is true: if $a$ is a unit, and $b$ is nilpotent, then $a+b$ is a unit.

The hint by Mark gives $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2$. How can you modify the second factor such that product is equal to $1$? (or said more simply: if the product of two elements is a unit, then both elements are actually units)

Comment: If $a-b$ is unit then its conjugate is also unit rigtlht

Answer (score 6):

consider $(a+b)(a-b)=a^{2}-b^{2}$

therefore we get $(a+b)(a-b)(a^{-2})=1$ which is $(a+b)(a^{-1}-ba^{-2})=1$

Comment: How does this lead to the conclusion that $a+b$ is a unit?